# Page not found when POST is using on laravel search form

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple search form with the POST method. When I hit the search button I got a 404 not found error. On `GET` it doesn't. I have created a connection to the already running server IP:PORT and got the result from there.

I have tried a number of solutions in other threads here but still doesn't work.

The form:

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="">
            <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="search" placeholder="Search..." required></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="submit">
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search</button>
         </div>
     </div>
```

The web.php (route)

```
Route::post('/search','App\Http\Controllers\SearchController@search')->name('search');
```

And the controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    try {
        // Get the search value from the request
        $search = $request->input('search');

        $host = "127.0.0.1";
        $port = 3000;
        $timeout=15;
        $sk = fsockopen($host, $port, $errnum, $errstr, $timeout);

        foreach(explode("\r\n", $search) as $line) {    
            $final = $line; 
        }

        fwrite($sk, $final);
        fclose($sk);

    } catch(Exception $e){
        return response($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
    return view('search', compact('final')); 
}
```

`php artisan route:list`

```
  GET|HEAD   / ....................................... SearchController@index
  POST       search .................................. search › SearchController@search
```

UPDATE
`php artisan optimize:clear`

```
INFO  Clearing cached bootstrap files.  

  events ................................. 1ms DONE
  views .................................. 2ms DONE
  cache .................................. 1ms DONE
  route .................................. 0ms DONE
  config ................................. 0ms DONE
  compiled ............................... 0ms DONE
```

`php artisan optimize`

```
   INFO  Caching the framework bootstrap files.  

  config ........................................ 6ms DONE
  routes ........................................ 6ms DONE
```

Comment: try php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which URL is used when submitting the form?

Comment: @NicoHaase, the URL of index is `http://localhost/sw/public/` when I submit the form it become `http://localhost/sw/public/search`. I have tried with `@csrf/ {{ csrf_field() }}` as in other thread suggested. I have added the `->name('search');` to the route.

Comment: fyi,`/public` should not appear in any Laravel URL, it should be your project's "DocumentRoot", either setup a valid vhost for each of your projects or use `php artisan serve` from your project folder

Comment: And is that URL the one you expect to be used?

Comment: @NicoHaase, if I understand you correctly - yes, because I didn't do the steps that bromber mentioned.

Comment: What is the value of your `APP_URL` in the .env file?

Comment: @brance, the default one - `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: But then the index page cannot be `http://localhost/sw/public/` or is that a page that you define das your index page? The POST request is sent to `http://localhost/search` that is why the `http://localhost/sw/public/search` is returning a 404 error.

Comment: I didn't define the index page. It is as the composer is installed it. When I open `http://localhost/sw/` I see all the directories and when I click on `public` it loads index page

Comment: Well then your server configuration is not correct, you should not see the list of directories and then click on the public folder. The localhost page should directly map to the public folder and show the index.php from that folder.

Comment: @Jake, run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed, thanks but no change.